# Make FileAlterationObserver to observe remote directory

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, apache-commons-io

How to make `FileAlterationObserver` to observe a remote directory?

This can accept a `String` path or a Java `File`. Both the cases it will look for the directory in local context. I have a directory in remote server file system.

It would be also helpful if anyone tell me how to create a new `File` object referring to the file in the remote directory.

Example:

```
File file = new File("remote directory path");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

- The `File` object cannot refer to an SFTP file.
- There's no way to have the SFTP server notify you on changes in a remote file/directory (the protocol itself does not have a mechanism for that).

All you can do is to use JSch (or other) SFTP interface to check for changes in regular intervals yourself.

Comment: Thank you. after all it was very simple, later I discovered it. Create a thread which will be running once for every 10 sec and use the Jsch API to perform a ls on a direcory and check for the added or removed files.